# Why input is not going from Python to Arduino board through serial port

Tags: python-3.x, arduino, serial-port, arduino-uno, arduino-ide

From Arduino IDE the input is responding and bulb is glowing. However, the same thing from Python is not working.

What is the issue?

### Desired Behavior

Arduino IDE serial input -> response behavior should match serial input -> response behavior with Python code.

LED bulb on Pin `13` should be set to `ON` / `HIGH` when serial port is written to with input `1`.

### Sample Code

Arduino code:

```cpp
void setup() {
  pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  if (Serial.available()) {
    char serialListener = Serial.read();
    if (serialListener == 1) {
      digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
    } else if (serialListener == 0) {
      digitalWrite(13, LOW);
    }
  }
}
```

Python code:

```
import serial

ser = serial.Serial('COM3', baudrate=9600, timeout=1)
ser.close()
ser.open()
ser.write("1".encode())
```

Comment: I think you mean `if (serialListener == '1') ` and `else if (serialListener == '0')`. What you have right now compares the _ASCII value_ of the character it receives to 0 or 1, which is not what you want.

Answer (score 1):

With `if (serialListener == 1)` you are expecting a byte with the value 1.
With `ser.write("1".encode())` you are sending a character `'1'` with an ASCII code 49.

You need to fix your comparison in Arduino to match what you are sending, so you are comparing characters not byte values.

```cpp
if (serialListener == '1') {
  digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
} else if (serialListener == '0') {
  digitalWrite(13, LOW);
}
```